# Can we conclude that the a sequence $a_n$ such that $ |a_1| \lt |a_2 -a_1| \lt |a_3 -a_2| \lt |a_4 - a_3| \dots$, and $a_1 \neq 0$ is increasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

We have an infinite sequence
$$
a_1, a_2 , a_3 \cdots 
$$
And it is given that
$$
|a_1| \lt |a_2 -a_1| \lt |a_3 -a_2| \lt |a_4 - a_3| \cdots \\
a_1 \neq 0
$$
(that is the difference between the subsequent terms are increasing and first term cannot be zero)

Can we conclude that the absolute values of subsequent terms are increasing? That is can we conclude
$$
|a_1| \lt |a_2| \lt |a_3| \lt |a_4| \cdots
$$
Playing around with the inequalities given in the question can give us the information that the alternate terms are increasing (in absolute/numerical value, leaving $a_1$ aside, that is, not comparing $a_1$ with any terms but just caring that it is not zero) but not the consecutive terms. So, I think we cannot conclude that the consecutive terms are numerically increasing.

An  explanatory answer is sought.

Comment: You are right. Take $a_1 = 1, a_2 = 3, a_3, = -1$. Now, $|1| < |2| < |4|$ holds but $|a_3| \not > |a_2|$

Comment: @Andrei In that case $|a_i| < |a_{i+1}|$ still holds

Comment: Thanks @JohnWhite. I will delete my comment

Comment: @JohnWhite Thank you. I think that’s the most we can conclude from that (alternate terms are increasing numerically) much info, right?

Comment: That is not true either. The same counterexample above works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the sequence $b_n:=c_n(1-\tfrac{1}{n})$ where $c_n\in\{+1,-1\}$, and the sequence $a_n:=\sum_{i=1}^nb_i$.

Then $|a_{n+1}-a_n|=|b_{n+1}|=1-\tfrac{1}{n+1}$ is increasing, yet because of the random choice of $c_i$ there is no telling whether $a_n$ is increasing or decreasing. Here is an example generated by a random choice of $c_n$.

[image]

Comment: But in your example I cannot see how alternate terms are increasing in absolute values. Can you please make me see it? I really liked your sophisticated example.

Comment: Should alternate terms be increasing? It is not stated in the question.

Comment: But we can obtain it by doing some algebra with the inequalities.

Comment: ? Take $c=(+1,+1,-1,-1)$ in the example, then $a_1$ increases to $a_3$ but decreases to $a_5$.

Comment: The example would be simpler if we take $b_n=(-1)^{c_n}$. I only took $1-1/n$ so as to satisfy the strict inequalities.

Comment: Then, $a_1 =-1$, $a_2= -2$, $a_3=-3$.

Comment: Sorry, I write stuff that's not in my head. I meant $(-1)^{c_n}$ to be $\pm1$, so $c_n\in\{0,1\}$. Anyway, take $(a_n)$ to increase twice in a row then decrease twice in a row.

Comment: Okay, then will get $$0, 1,0, 1 \cdots$$ that is alternate terms are equal.

Comment: No you get $0,0.5,1.25,0.45,-0.38$.

Comment: $a_1$ cannot be zero is stated in the question.

Comment: Add 1 to everything then. $1,1.5,2.25,1.45,0.62$.

Comment: Thanks for the patience and good explanation.

Comment: Welcome! My mistakes don't help.

Answer (score 4):

One counterexample suffices, and you can produce one with just three terms. If you want to go a little further and show that there need not even be a point beyond which the terms increase in absolute value, you have to work a little harder, but not much. For instance, let $a_1=1$, and in general let

$$a_{n+1}=\begin{cases}
a_n-n,&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\\
a_n+n,&\text{if }n\text{ is even,}
\end{cases}$$

so that you get the sequence $1,0,2,-1,3,\ldots\;$; it’s not hard to show by induction that in that case $a_{2n-1}=n$ and $a_{2n}=1-n$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. Evidently $|a_{n+1}-a_n|=n$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, but $|a_{2n}|=n-1<n=|a_{2n-1}|$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$.

Comment: Alternate terms are increasing numerically. But subsequent terms are not. Yes, I can see it in your example.